# how to show url response data in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

```html
{
  "response": {
    "metadata": {
      "requestDateTime": "2022-06-21T18:21:31.505Z",
      "responseDateTime": "2022-06-21T18:21:31.505Z",
      "deprecated": false
    },
    "status": {
      "success": true,
      "code": "",
      "description": "",
      "help": ""
    },
    "results": {
      "customerId": "948293",
      "personas": [
        {
          "id": "CUST",
          "description": "Customer"
        }
      ],
      "events": [
        {
          "id": 9482923,
          "cause": {
            "id": "881",
            "description": "Tire went flat"
          },
          "unit": 0,
          "location": {
            "city": "San Fancisco",
            "state": "CA"
          },
          "created": "2022-06-21T18:21:35.505Z",
          "currentStage": {
            "id": "DSFW",
            "description": "Something is very wrong"
          },
          "accounting": {
            "workCompleted": "2022-06-25T17:22:35.505Z",
            "status": {
              "id": "COST",
              "description": "Costing"
            },
            "invoiced": "2022-06-25T17:22:35.505Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
</br></br>
<table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered"  cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Metadata</th>
            <th>Results</th>
            <th>Response</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- data -->
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {

    $.ajax({
        url : 'https://e3b36496-1168-4841-9ed2-9d44c93d1d4d.mock.pstmn.io/v2/agent-assist-profile/9047478154',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response) {
        var metadata = response;
        console.log(metadata);
            bindtoDatatable(metadata);
        }
    });



});

function bindtoDatatable(metadata) {
        var table = $('#table_id').dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "aaData" : metadata,
            "columns" : [ {
                "data" : metadata.requestDateTime
            }, {
                "data" : metadata.responseDateTime
            } ]
        })
    }
</script>
</html>
```

URL: https://e3b36496-1168-4841-9ed2-9d44c93d1d4d.mock.pstmn.io/v2/agent-assist-profile/9047478154
i want to display complete above url response data into datatable.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: RTD: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i tried, but it is not showing data. i have added the code which i have tried

Comment: Can you show us your JSON response (as formatted text) from the Ajax request? I know you have provided a link, but I prefer not to click on it...

Comment: (Just as a side note: you are using deprecated (but still usable) options such as `aaData`. Unless you are using a very old version of DataTables, you can use the newer values such as `data`. See [Converting parameter names for 1.10](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).)

Comment: @andrewJames I have attached the json response to my code.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Your JSON does not have any repeating array entries anywhere, so there is nothing for DataTables to iterate over, to build the rows of table data. It's not clear to me what you want the end result to look like. Can you show us, using that JSON data? (If you just want all the data to be displayed in a single table row, then I am not sure what the point is of using DataTables for that. Hence an example would help.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map your data, see https://datatables.net/examples/

here is a very basic example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#table_id').dataTable({
    ajax: function(x, reply) {
      fetch('https://e3b36496-1168-4841-9ed2-9d44c93d1d4d.mock.pstmn.io/v2/agent-assist-profile/9047478154')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => map(x, reply, data));
    },
    columns: [{
        data: 'Metadata'
      },
      {
        data: 'Results'
      },
      {
        data: 'Response'
      }
    ]
  })

  function map(x, reply, data) {
    return reply({
      "data": [{
        "Metadata": data.response.metadata.requestDateTime,
        "Results": data.response.results.customerId,
        "Response": data.response.status.success,
      }]
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Metadata</th>
          <th>Results</th>
          <th>Response</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!-- data -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank u This works, but in second column we have to show complete data like customer id, personas data and events data in this single column. is this possible?